# get a list item pointed to a item of the same type c#

Tags: c#, list, pointers

there is any way to do something like that

```
List<Myclass> classlist = new List<Myclass>();
```

`Myclass * item = &classlist.ElementAt(0);`

and when i change a value in item, is changed in the list item too?

ex:
item.name = "changedme";
and when i access to the classlist.ElementAt(0).name, the value is "changedme" ???

thanks

Comment: Technically, it already is just a pointer in the list. The full object isnt actually what's in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Class` is really a class and not a struct, all you have to do is:

```
var classList = new List<Class>();
var instance = classList[0];
instance.name = "changedme";
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword; you might want to change your example! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the object in your list is a reference type, it will work exactly as you specified.